# Different behaviour of range in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't find the answer as why this code for range loop, behaves OK in 2.7 and not in 3.4.

```
from graphics import *


def main():
    win = GraphWin("Click Me!")
    for i in range(10):
        p = win.getMouse()

        print("you clicked at:", p.getX() , p.getY())


 main()
```

output on 2.7 is: `"you clicked at: 56 77 "`  once I click

output on 3.4 is" `"you clicked at:"` once I click then, 56 77
                   `"you clicked at:`

Is it range behaving different or print?

Comment: This is a pretty straight forward question, that includes code and a clear description of the problem. Its not worth the downvote brigade.

Comment: Perhaps in 3.4 you're getting both a down-click and an up-click event.

Comment: Well it behaves like this one down + up event = half of what i have inside print. one more time and prints p.get(), p.gety() in the same line but also prints the next "you clicked at:" in the next line. Also if you remove the loop and make it work for once it works. But i can't figure out why this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**In Python 2 [`print` is a statement](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#print)**, and this:

```
print("you clicked at:", p.getX() , p.getY())
```

prints the tuple `("you clicked at:", p.getX() , p.getY())`, which my default puts a space between each entry.

**In Python 3, [`print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)** and you are calling it with the arguments:

```
"you clicked at:", p.getX() , p.getY()
```

As the documentation shows:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

---

Addendum:

After some research on the `GraphWin`, it appears that you are using the [Zelle Graphics library.](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) Which has been updated once since 2011 to correct a small 2-to-3 issue, and some universities appear to be using a much older version.

I didn't delve much deeper in but I think that there is going to be a few incompatibilities in the library so may not be able to do a straight switch to Python 3.

Comment: But why when i remove the `for i in range(10)` in python 3, the output is right in one line?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why that is, but the `range` function isn't causing your problem, its that you are using `print` incorrectly.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem: `sep` and `end` have to be keyword arguments, don't they? From the docs: `All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end.`

Comment: I understand i did it in python 2, i treated it as a function. But again in Python 3 once i remove the for range loop the output is different and i think print is being used property, like xnx said shouldnt the keyword arguments be preceded by an end and sep?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think you might be right about Zelle's module. But i still find strange that by removing the loop makes it work.